# Change Optimoptions to optimset because of matlab R2011a

Tags: matlab

I am using `optimoptions` function in MATLAB R2015a. The syntax is as follows :

```
options = optimoptions('fmincon','Display','iter','MaxFunEvals',3000000); 
fx = @(x)modifiedLogLikelihood(x,len,ET,counta,vals,INT);
parameters = fmincon(fx,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,[],options);
```

I would like to run the same code on R2011a, but I am getting the following error since `optimoptions` was introduced after R2011a.

> Undefined function or method 'optimoptions' for input arguments of type 'char'.

I referred to [this document](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=8758317), that suggested me to use optimset.

I tried to take their advice and wrote:

```
options = optimset('fmincon','Display','iter',3000000); 
fx = @(x)modifiedLogLikelihood(x,len,ET,counta,vals,INT);
parameters = fmincon(fx,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,[],options);
```

But it yields the following error:

> Error using ==> optimset at 198
>
> Unrecognized parameter name 'fmincon'. Please see the optimset reference page in the
>       documentation for a list of acceptable option parameters. Link to reference page.

How can I use `optimset` to get the equivalent set of parameters as I was able to obtain with `optimoptions`. I would be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's helpful if you read the [documentation page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/optimset.html) for a function when trying to use it.

With `optimset` you want to get the default parameters using just the `'fmincon'` string as input and then use `optimset` again to modify just  the parameters that you would like to change from their default value.

```
options = optimset('fmincon');
options = optimset(options, 'Display', 'iter', 'MaxFunEvals', 3000000);
```